# Insert into columns with the same data type

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a way to "sort" data types in sql. For example, I have two tables built like this:

```
create table test1 
(
    columnone varchar(max),
    columntwo text,
    columnthree datetime,
    columnfour int
);

create table test2 
(
    column1 text,
    column2 varchar(max),
    column3 int,
    column4 datetime
);

insert into test2 (column1, column2, column3, column4)
values ('foo', 'suit3333', 7, 7/4/24)

insert into test2 (column1, column2, column3, column4)
values ('bar', 'person24', 9, 6/31/22)
```

I need to match the columns in test2 with the columns with the same datatypes in test1, and insert the data.

For example, I would need to insert the `varchar` (`column2`) in `test2` into the empty `columnone` in `test1`. This needs to be done for all the columns.

In my attempt, I tried selecting the first column, using a while loop to use "magical" dynamic SQL to match the column with the same datatype, insert it, and then drop that first column. Repeat.

This didn't work because I don't know how to properly use dynamic SQL.

Comment: Thats a very strange requirement - why do you need to do that generically without writing a specific SQL query - which is what SQL is designed for?

Comment: What if there are two columns with the same type?

Comment: `column1 text,` Nope - start over. This datatype has been deprecated for almost 20 years.

Comment: @SMor, these are just example datatypes.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to create a view for `test2` that has the same column names as `test1`. Then you can insert into `test2` using the same names as used in `test1`.

It would look something like this:

```
create table test1 (
    columnone varchar(max),
    columntwo text,
    columnthree datetime,
    columnfour int
);

create table test2 (
    column1 text,
    column2 varchar(max),
    column3 int,
    column4 datetime
);

CREATE VIEW test2View
AS
SELECT 
    column1 as columntwo,
    column2 as columnone,
    column3 as columnfour,
    column4 as columnthree
FROM   test2;
```

Then we can

```
insert into test1 (columnone, columntwo, columnthree, columnfour)
values
( 'one','two', '4/4/2024', 4)

insert into test2View (columnone, columntwo, columnthree, columnfour)
values
( 'one','two', '4/4/2024', 4)
```

Comment: Thing is, it needs to be done dynamically, this might help me in creating a loop to check datatypes and add them.